# How to set multiple homepage for ie and chrome with batch file?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, batch-file, registry

I use this to set one IE homepage, but I can't set multiple homepage.
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "http://www.google.com/" /F 
 
Is it possible to add multiple homepage for the ie and chrome browser?

Comment: it's not stored in registry but in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`  , but in the latest versions of chrome it's not in readable format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Google chrome :**

The answer to the question is No ! you can not use the home page to open multiple windows in Google chrome as in FF (Firefox can open multiple homepages. Divide them by a | sign).

You can have multiple pages open on startup, but you can't have more than one page open when you click the Home button.

**But there is a work around....**

Just paste following javascript into the "Home Page" pref field (under your Chrome options) and it works as expected when clicking the "Home" button :

```
javascript:(function(){ window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'; window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/'); window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com/'); })();
```

thus you can add as many URLs as you want.

**In Internet Explorer:**

Yes, you can do that using below :

```
@ECHO off
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.google.com" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Secondary Start Pages" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "http://www.stackoverflow.com\0http://www.superuser.com\0" /f
```